# How can I write a genetic programming algorithm, given that the Halting problem is unsolvable?

Tags: halting-problem, genetic-algorithms

I am learning genetic programming and to practice I want to write a simple algorithm which evolves a program that solves a simple function (say, square root). I intend to represent programs as abstract syntax trees.

However, one of the functors is the while loop. Of course, in assesting a tree's fitness, I have to evaluate the program: but the halting problem is unsolvable. How can I tell if a given tree stops? Of course I can't, so what are some practicals ways to approach this problem?

Should I make my simple tree-language not turing complete? Or maybe give a timeout to each tree?

Answer (score 2):

It is very unlikely indeed that finiteness is truly what you are looking for. Would you *really* be happy with a program that takes $10^{10^{40}}$ steps to complete?

If I am right, "non-haltingness" is not the real quality you are looking for. It is "halting within a reasonable time".

The best way to express this is not as a pure timeout, but by defining a measure of utility which declines with an increasing number of steps. That will give your evolutionary mechanism a steady "push" in the right direction. As for whether it is $1/n$, $1/\sqrt n$, $2^{-n/c}$, that is something you can decide.

Of course in practice a program that takes more than a certain number of steps is going to carry on going for ever. But you can encapsulate this intuition into the algorithm by saying that if, after $n$ steps, the overall utility has declined to a point when it is too low to be worth considering *and* it is never going to increase if you carry on stepping. Thus the timeout is still there, but as an implementation detail and not as a primary principle-in-itself.